# how to replace entire array using jq in shell script?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Having the following structure:

```
{
  "DistributionConfig": {
    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
      "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
        "Quantity": 3,
        "Items": [
          {
            "LambdaFunctionARN": "3",
            "EventType": "origin-response",
            "IncludeBody": false
          },
          {
            "LambdaFunctionARN": "2",
            "EventType": "viewer-request",
            "IncludeBody": false
          },
          {
            "LambdaFunctionARN": "1",
            "EventType": "origin-request",
            "IncludeBody": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I extracted the items and modified them using the following:

```
export lambdaFunctionAssociations=$(echo $json |  jq '.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items' |
 jq 'map(if .EventType == "origin-response"
          then . + {"LambdaFunctionARN":'$originResponse'}
          else .
          end
         )'  |
jq 'map(if .EventType == "viewer-request"
          then . + {"LambdaFunctionARN":'$viewerRequest'}
          else .
          end
         )' |
jq 'map(if .EventType == "origin-request"
          then . + {"LambdaFunctionARN":'$originRequest'}
          else .
          end
         )')
```

Now I have the following stored in lambdaFunctionAssociations:

```
[
  {
    "LambdaFunctionARN": "ZZZ",
    "EventType": "origin-response",
    "IncludeBody": false
  },
  {
    "LambdaFunctionARN": "YYY",
    "EventType": "viewer-request",
    "IncludeBody": false
  },
  {
    "LambdaFunctionARN": "XXX",
    "EventType": "origin-request",
    "IncludeBody": false
  }
]
```

I want to replace the "Items": in the org json trying this:

```
export updatedCloudFrontConf=$(echo $json | jq '.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items='$lambdaFunctionAssociations'')
```

with thefollowing error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items=[
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to diminish your efforts at all, but that's not how we use jq. You can do this in a single call, e.g:

```
jq --arg originResponse ZZZ --arg viewerRequest YYY --arg originRequest XXX '
.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items |= map(
  .EventType as $t | .LambdaFunctionARN =
    if $t == "origin-response" then $originResponse
    elif $t == "viewer-request" then $viewerRequest
    elif $t == "origin-request" then $originRequest
    else . end
)' file
```